# One-To-Many relation with a specific order in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I want to have a kind of array in my model to save instances of another model in a specific order, but I found out that you can't use an ArrayField of ForeignKeys.

There is the Questionary model, that contains multiple questions that have to be in a certain order. And this questions have to be able to reorder or be deleted.

Something like:

```
class Questionary(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=False, blank=False)
   ...

class Question(models.Model):
   text = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=False, blank=False)
   ...
   questionary = models.ForeignKey(Questionary, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I don't know how to make the Question model have a specific order in the questionary and let this order be edited.

I thought maybe add a field in the Question called 'index' and edit that when the Questions are reordered, but that seems a little bit inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your biggest concern is in maintaining and editing the order.

To that effect this library:

https://github.com/django-ordered-model/django-ordered-model

allows you to manage and edit an ordered field as you described using the `order_with_respect_to` functionality and the built in , ie.

```
from ordered_model.models import OrderedModel

class Questionary(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=False, blank=False)
   ...

class Question(OrderedModel):
   text = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=False, blank=False)
   ...
   questionary = models.ForeignKey(Questionary, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   order_with_respect_to = 'questionary'
```

now you can have a set of questions as a member of your questionary like so

```
questionary = Questionary.objects.create(name='all about goats')

one = Question.objects.create(text='what is a group of goats called?', questionary=questionary)
two = Question.objects.create(text='who is the cutest goat?', questionary=questionary)
three = Question.objects.create(text='what shape is a goats pupil?', questionary=questionary)

# questionary.question_set.all()
# now returns QuerySet([one, two, three])
```

and the questions will be returned via `questionary.question_set.all()` in the order in which they were declared

additionally you can reorder them using the various techniques listed in the tutorial

```
one.down()
# questionary.question_set.all() 
# now returns two, one, three

two.swap(three)
# questionary.question_set.all() 
# now returns three, one, two
```